How do I push Go artifacts to a repository using Github actions?
I am currently trying to Go build artifacts of an application and this is my current pipeline
name: Build and Push Docker Image and Go Artifacts

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - jfrog-dev  # Your specified branch
  workflow_dispatch:  # Allows manual triggering of the workflow

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Step 1: Check out the code from the repository
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Step 2: Verify JFROG_URL and USER
      - name: Verify credentials
        run: |
          echo "JFROG_URL is ${JFROG_URL}"
          echo "JFROG_USER is ${JFROG_USER}"

      # Step 3: Set up Go environment
      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: '1.23'

      # Step 4: Install dependencies and build Go binary
      - name: Install dependencies and build Go binary
        run: |
          go mod tidy
          go build -o mit-sphere ./cmd/main.go

      # Step 5: Install JFrog CLI
      - name: Install JFrog CLI
        run: |
          curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh
          sudo mv jfrog /usr/local/bin/
          echo "JFrog CLI version:"
          jfrog --version

      # Step 6: Log in to JFrog Artifactory for Docker
      - name: Log in to JFrog Artifactory for Docker
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.JFROG_PASSWORD }}" | docker login mani.jfrog.io -u "${{ secrets.JFROG_USER }}" --password-stdin

      # Step 7: Build and tag Docker image
      - name: Build and tag Docker image
        run: |
          docker build . -t mit-sphere:latest
          docker tag mit-sphere:latest mani.jfrog.io/mani1234-maniit/mit-sphere:latest

      # Step 8: Push Docker image to JFrog Artifactory
      - name: Push Docker image to JFrog Artifactory
        run: |
          docker push mani.jfrog.io/mani1234-maniit/mit-sphere:latest

      # Step 9: Configure JFrog CLI with username and password
      - name: Configure JFrog CLI
        run: |
          jfrog config add artifactory --url "https://mani.jfrog.io" --user "${{secrets.JFROG_USER }}" --password "${{ secrets.JFROG_PASSWORD }}" --interactive=false

      # Step 10: Deploy Go artifact to JFrog Artifactory
      - name: Deploy Go artifact to JFrog Artifactory
        run: |
          echo "Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory"
          jfrog gp mit-sphere-new-go 1 --server-id rt-server # 1 - stands for version number

There seems to be something wrong with the parameters and here is the error I get.
Run echo "Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory"
  echo "Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory"
  jfrog go-publish mit-sphere-new-go 1 --build-name my-go-build --build-number 1 --server-id rt-server
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GOROOT: /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.23.2/x64
Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory
No help topic for 'go-publish'
Error: Process completed with exit code 3.

Here is my go.yaml with the deployer repo info
version: 1
type: go
resolver:
  repo: mit-sphere-new-go
  serverId: manifest
deployer:
  repo: mani1234-manii
  serverId: manifest

I've tried jfrog go publish, jfrog go-publish and jf gp as well. The errors are pretty similar. Some help on this would be great. Thanks!

"mit-sphere-new-go" ? If I Google it, I find this blog article which just uses "go": https://jfrog.com/blog/using-the-jfrog-cli-to-create-go-modules/ . Besides the parameters being of the "name=value" variety.

you don't need mit-sphere-new-go, or at least I don't see it in the command help. it should be jfrog gp 1 --server-id rt-server

This is error I encounter:
Run echo "Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory"   echo "Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory"   jfrog gp 1 --server-id rt-server    shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}   env:     GOROOT: /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.23.2/x64 Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory No help topic for 'gp' 
Error: Process completed with exit code 3. '

This command downloads the latest v1 version of the JFrog CLI:
curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh

Note that this version was released 2 years ago and does not include the go-publish command.
To download the latest v2 version of the JFrog CLI, I recommend one of the following methods:

Use the Setup JFrog CLI GitHub Action (Recommended)
Install JFrog CLI using this command:

curl -fL https://install-cli.jfrog.io | sh

The above command installs JFrog CLI in your PATH, eliminating the need to manually move it to /usr/local/bin/. Also, please note that the executable is named jf instead of jfrog.
For more installation options, visit JFrog CLI Installation page: https://jfrog.com/getcli/.

the curl command solved the cli versioning problem but I got the following error:
Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory 09:15:26 [Info] Using go: go1.23.2 {   "status": "failure",   "totals": {     "success": 0, 09:15:26 [Info] Trace ID for JFrog Platform logs: c8d9806f8b6be527 Error: 6 [Error] the deployer repository is missing from the config file (/home/runner/work/mit-sphere/mit-sphere/.jfrog/projects/go.yaml)     "failure": 0 please run 'jf go-config' with your deployer repository information   } } Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Here are my last two stages of ci.yaml (updated)
`# Step 10: Configure Go for JFrog
- name: Configure Go for JFrog
run: |
jf go-config --repo-resolve=mit-sphere-new-go --server-id-resolve=manifest
#----
Step 11: Deploy Go artifact to JFrog Artifactory using new syntax
  - name: Deploy Go artifact to JFrog Artifactory
    run: |
       echo "Publishing Go package to JFrog Artifactory"
       jf gp mit-sphere-new-go-local v1.0.0 --build-name=my-go-build --build-number=1 `

I've followed the documentation based syntax. Also,added go.yaml

You missed the --repo-deploy & --server-id-deploy flags in the jf go-config command: https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-artifactory/package-managers-integration#building-go-packages
